# Getting Error on Oracle Export Schemas

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-12170

**execute following Command**

```
expdp scott/tiger@orcl schemas=EMPLOYEES directory=DB_BAK dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=expdpSCOTT.log
```

**Getting this error** when I execute above command for export Schemas

```
Export: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Mar 12 12:16:05 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

UDE-12170: operation generated ORACLE error 12170

ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

Please help.

Comment: Is the instance running?  Is the listener running? Are you running expdp on the server or remotely?  Is there a firewall involved?

Comment: instance and listener both running. And I tried in locally not in remote. And there no firewall.

Comment: @Tanim I have the same problem. What was the solution?